# How to add column header to excel sheet?

Tags: c#, excel

```
private void btn_gnrt_files_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

    if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "")
    {
        //reading text file
        FileInfo theSourceFile = new FileInfo(@"" + textBox1.Text);   
        StreamReader reader = theSourceFile.OpenText();
        String filename = "";
        String text = "";
        do
        {
            text = reader.ReadLine();
            if (text != null)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(""+state);
                String[] fname = text.Split('|'); //writiting file
                if (state == true)
                { 
                    filename = fname[1];
                    filename.TrimStart();
                    //MessageBox.Show(filename);
                    Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
                    excel.Visible = true;
                    //true is append parameter
                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"" + textBox2.Text + @"\" + filename.TrimStart() + ".csv", true))
                    writer.WriteLine(text.Replace("|", ","));
```

I get excel files with data through this code. but i cant 
put column headers to excel sheets. plz tell me how to add these headers

```
<<reg no,br no,pr no,curency>>
```

Comment: i want to add <<reg no,br no, pr no, curency>> as the column headers.. plz help me

Comment: Move that "using StreamWriter" statement to before the loop (so that the whole loop is contained withing the "using"): you want to open it once, append all lines, then close it, instead of doing that for every line.

Answer (score 2):

```
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                if (xlApp == null)
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
                    return;
                }
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
                xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);


                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "reg no";
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "br no"
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "pr no"
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "curency";
```

And then do your business...

Answer (score 1):

Column headers are just regular cells in Excel (or CSV), so add them as a first line.

Add that header-line before you start the loop to write the data lines.